# Flash Media - USB Sticks, SD Cards or SDD drives the same?

Tags: filesystems, usb-flash-drive

I mean, same tech inside, just different form factor or interface?

It's said that Flash media has limited amount of reads and writes. Does that apply equally to any of those types?

Would it be a good idea to use a flash friendly filesystem ([like F2FS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F2FS)).

The place I am coming from is whether it's doable to run a Linux Server from a USB stick (2.0 or 3) and how to do that best.

Comment: true. but isn't opinion always involved in such matters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definitely not.

There is a limit on the number of times a block can be erased and for all normal purposes a block must be erased before being written, so in normal use there is a limit on the number of writes.  Some drives will shut down gracefully upon reaching a specified number of writes, some will simply fail when a block is worn out.  The form factor makes no difference in this regard.

However, in practice SSD drives will last longer than flash drives and SD cards (as they are the same as flash drives I will omit them from further discussion.)  The difference is the sophistication of their controllers.

Flash drives have fairly simple controllers.  When asked to write a block they will pick an available block with a lower write count and write it.

SSD drives use this same approach.  However, SSD drives can also decide to select a block with a low write count that is **not** available, move the contents into a block that has been written a lot and then make the low write count block available.

The net result is the flash drive uses up it's life expectancy only from the empty space on the drive, or space otherwise freed up by the writing.  Blocks which hold data that doesn't get written will not have their life used up.

Picture a system that is 90% full of fixed data (say, the operating system) and the remaining 10% is for temporary storage.  If this is on a flash drive it will fail with 90% of it's life remaining, whereas the SSD will shuffle the blocks around and use up the whole life of the drive before dying--thus giving 10x the life in this admittedly extreme case.

SSD drives also have status reporting that lets you query the remaining life.  Flash drives do not.

Comment: thanks. Also found some other insights (similar to the points raised by Loren) [here](https://superuser.com/questions/513240/operating-systems-on-sd-cards) in the meantime.

Comment: any thoughts on F2Fs being beneficial?